# How to add Lottie Animation in my Kivymd App?

Tags: animation, kivy, python-3.8, kivymd

I wanted to add Lottie Animation in Kivymd, so I downloaded Lottie file but I don't know what to do next.

And I tried to download animation as GIF file and add it to my app, but when I add GIF with AsyncImage, It moves so slowly.

Is there a widget that shows Lottie Animation in Kivymd? Or is there some other ways to show Lottie Animation is my screen?

My Lottie File: [Loading-Spinner](https://lottiefiles.com/9965-loading-spinner)
OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.8

Thanks!

Comment: You can adjust the speed of a `gif` in `AsyncImage` using the [anim_delay](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.anim_delay) property.

Comment: It worked! Thank. Plus: Is there any relation between animation's frame and anim_delay?

Comment: The `anim_delay` is the delay between frame display.